# Break string enclosed in <span> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styling

I wanted to change the "**Lessons**" into the "**Songs**", as **0 of 22** dynamic value it will increment as someone clicks the button. I've tried with this code but it isn't incrementing the number:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  if ($('#completion-count').length && !$('.completion_count_no_repeat').length) {
    $('#completion-count').empty();
    $("#completion-count").append(`<span id="completion-count" class="font-semibold">0 of 22 Songs Completed</span>`);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="completion-count" class="font-semibold">0 of 22 Lessons Completed</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing the number.

You need to keep count of the last number and then format it into the string:

```js
let index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  if ($('#completion-count').length && !$('.completion_count_no_repeat').length) {
    $('#completion-count').empty();
    $("#completion-count").append(`<span id="completion-count" class="font-semibold">${index} of 22 Songs Completed</span>`)
  }
  index++;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="completion-count" class="font-semibold">0 of 22 Lessons Completed</span>
```

The curly braces in the string are for templating. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)